# OpenLayers 3 : Drawing a polygon feature over the dateline

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am attempting to draw a simple box polygon that overlaps the international dateline.  Currently when creating the polygon it wraps in the opposite direction.

Full example : http://jsfiddle.net/mcroteau/dkk2yu3L/

**Desired Output :**

[image: Desired Polygon]

**Actual Output :**

[image]

**Javascript:**

```
var wgs84Proj = new ol.proj.Projection({ code : "EPSG:4326" });
var origProj = new ol.proj.Projection({ code : "EPSG:900913" });

var mapTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});


var convertedCoordinates = [];            
var unformattedCoordinates = [[175, 70], [175, 60], [-160, 60], [-160, 70]];


$(unformattedCoordinates).each(function(index, coordinate){
    var lat = coordinate[0];
    var lon = coordinate[1];

    var circle = new ol.geom.Circle([lat, lon])
    circle.transform(wgs84Proj, origProj);

    convertedCoordinates.push(circle.getCenter());
});

var polygonGeometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([convertedCoordinates])
var polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({ geometry : polygonGeometry });

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(polygonFeature);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
}); 


var mapView = new ol.View({
    center: [-19000000, 9500000],
    zoom: 3
})

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers : [mapTile],
    target : 'map',
    view   : mapView
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

I'm not sure if there is a config setting that I missed in the OpenLayers 3 API or a conversion that must be made on the data points.  Any guidance would be most appreciated.

**Updated Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/mcroteau/edt92p23/

Comment: I'm not sure what you've tried to do, but take a look at a map with coordinates - the rectangle you've drawn is exactly the one that belongs to your coordinates. Do you have a reference picture to show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No need to create Circle objects, just use "var xy = ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')" and then push(xy). Also you have lat-lon designations reversed, but it doesn't matter, it's just the names that are wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Just add 360 degrees (or whatever is the total width of the used projection) to your X coordinates to make them positioned in the world to the right. Change `[[175, 70], [175, 60], [-160, 60], [-160, 70]]` to `[[175, 70], [175, 60], [200, 60], [200, 70]]`.

OpenLayers works with projected coordinates. `[-160, 70]` is to the left/west of `[175, 70]`, so any line drawn between the points will go left (as in your example). To get it to go right/east, you have to make sure the X coordinate is higher.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkk2yu3L/4/

Comment: Hi Alvin, I found a situation where the adjustment doesn't completely resolve the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/mcroteau/edt92p23/5/.  Any ideas what I might need to do?

Comment: In your linked example, the coordinate you modify is around 340 degress east of the others. Adding 360 degrees to that makes it 700 degrees east (which is what you do), while deducting 360 degrees make it 20 degrees west of the others. You have to adapt you algorithm to see if you need to add or remove 360 degrees to get closer to the others.

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest Im not sure I completely understand.  Would you be willing to include an example?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure that it is possible, Openlayer can't draw between two instance of the world!

I you deactivate the wrapX function you can see what he see:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidhequet/dkk2yu3L/3/

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX:false});
vectorSource.addFeature(polygonFeature);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});
```